# Enabling preview in QGIS recent projects?

Tags: qgis

after installing qgis on win 10 I am missing the map-preview in the recent projects window as I had under win7(see screenshot). where is the setting to enable this?[image]

Comment: Have you installed the same version of QGIS? This feature was introduced in 2.12. I have it installed on Windows 10 and can see recent projects.

Comment: I installed using the standalone-version. I see recent projects (text-info about path, used projection...) , but I don not see the preview of the map-canavas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To see the preview thumbnail you need to open and save the project. Then when you reopen QGIS you should see the image

Answer (score 3):

Working from Linux here but the program is identical. The option you're looking for is under the general options -> "Project files" tab.

[image]

The option for opening projects on launch can be set to the "Welcome Page" (What you're looking for), to open up the last/specific project, or to simply show a blank canvas. It's possible that when you upgraded your installation, this setting may have changed.

Comment: I have enabled this, and I do have recent-projects, but only text-info and no preview of the map-canavas